# When using www I don't get the api results, I get them if used without www

Tags: javascript, asp.net, api

When I open a page like this `www.mywebsite.in` it's not showing my data. However, when I open my website page without `www` I can get the results from the database.

I'm using `get` and `post` api to get the json data, but while loading the page I get an error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://mywebsite.in/values/get. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
public class YourController : ApiController
{
}
```

Comment: Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Cors' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Http' (are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: install Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors this from nuget package

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.EnableCors();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: once you install this package, in App_Start, WebApiConfig.cs class you have to add   config.EnableCors(); method to enable CORS for your API. And use [EnableCors("*", "*", "*")] attribute on your controller to access it from different origin.

Comment: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api